# Warning when archive my app in Xcode

Tags: xcode, build, app-store, warnings, archive

My problem is as follows:
I'm trying to upload my first application in iTunes Connect, but I get the warning:
**Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)**

My first steps:
I remove on my mac (and revoke in provisioning portal) all certificate and provisioning profile.

After that my keychain is fully empty.

Step 2:
I go to the **Keychain Access** and create new **Generating a Certificate Signing Request**
[image]

[image]

Step 3:
Save CSR to disk.

Step 4:
Go to the my provisioning portal and request CSR from my mac in Distribution Certificate part

After some time I download new Distribution Certificate and install it in my Keychain. A couple of minutes - and my certificate get valid status (Certificate is valid)

Step 5:
So, I go to the provisioning and create new distribution profile with next settings:

[image]

After that I submit and download new distribution certificate and install it into my Xcode.

[image]

So, ok - this is first part

Next...

I create new app and setup all needed settings.

After archive i get this warning:

**warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)**

[image]

Can you help me?

Thanks all!

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of your Build Settings page? (open the project, click the root item on the list of files, then targets -> "app name", then on the build settings column. Just look for the area marked code signing.